# Yii Rights :: Error 403 You Are Not Authorized To Perform This Action

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am newb in yii. I installed yii-rights in protected/modules/rights as per documentation. But can't use properly. There are something missing that I couldn't find out. localhost/index.php/right page is working well. But when I press on "permissions", "roles", "tasks", "operations". It shows

"Error 403
You are not authorized to perform this action."

Here is my main config::

```
'import'=>array(
 'application.modules.right.*',
 'application.modules.right.models*',
 'application.modules.rights.components.*',
 ),
'rights'=>array(

 'superuserName'=>'Admin', // Name of the role with super user privileges.
 'authenticatedName'=>'Authenticated', // Name of the authenticated user role.
 'userIdColumn'=>'id', // Name of the user id column in the database.
 'userNameColumn'=>'username', // Name of the user name column in the database.
 'enableBizRule'=>true, // Whether to enable authorization item business rules.
 'enableBizRuleData'=>false, // Whether to enable data for business rules.
 'displayDescription'=>true, // Whether to use item description instead of name.
 'flashSuccessKey'=>'RightsSuccess', // Key to use for setting success flash messages.
 'flashErrorKey'=>'RightsError', // Key to use for setting error flash messages.

 'baseUrl'=>'/rights', // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested.
  'layout'=>'rights.views.layouts.main', // Layout to use for displaying Rights.
  'appLayout'=>'application.views.layouts.main', // Application layout.
  'cssFile'=>'rights.css', // Style sheet file to use for Rights.
 'install'=>false, // Whether to enable installer.
'debug'=>false,
),
'components'=>array(
  'user'=>array(
  'class'=>'RWebUser',
   // enable cookie-based authentication
  'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
  'loginUrl'=>array('/user/login'),

 ),
```

## AssignementController

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // Allow superusers to access Rights

                        'actions'=>array(
                'view',
                'user',
                'revoke',
            ),
            'users'=>$this->_authorizer->getSuperusers(),
        ),
        array('deny', // Deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

I need your help. PLEASE

Note that:: I am using yii-user also. yii-user is working well.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you are required to name your action to perform function.

```
  public function accessRules(){
    .......   
    array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                    'actions'=>array('create','update','districts','center'),
                    'users'=>array('@'),
    ......
    }
```

For example in the above code, district and center are actions.
Hopefully, you will get the idea.

Comment: It's not working ::: my controller:: 'actions'=>array('view','user','revoke',),
'users'=>$this->_authorizer->getSuperusers(),

Comment: please help me with some proper solution. I failed to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an older question but have you add

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl',
    );
}
```

to the AssignementController? Yii needs it to regard function `accessRules()` for access controlling.

Answer (score 0):

Set your "Yii::app()->user->name";

Try this

```
<?php
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity 
{
protected $_id;
const USER_INACTIVE = 3;

public function authenticate() 
{
    $p= Person::model()->findByUsername($this->username);
    if (empty($p))
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    elseif (!CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($this->password, $p->password))
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id = $p->id;
        $this->username = $p->username;

        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->_id;
}
```

}

the line "$this->username = $p->username;";

Hope this help.